# Publish Web and View in Firefox are using two different Databases

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-5

I don't really know how to title this question.
I have an MVC project web site.
I wanted the login system to have roles, so I implemented that. I noticed that when I published my website, the localdb Entity framework DB with the login users weren't working. 
So I edited the DefaultAppPool settings to allow the localdb to be used when I publish web.

I thought everything was working, I could log in. Great!
Though, I noticed I could not log into my admin account. Only when I used IIS express, the test debug (View in Firefox) option I could.

I registered a new account in the "View in Firefox", checked my SQL Server Object explorer for the tables, view data, and saw the new account there.

I publish web, create an account; it does not appear there, and I cannot log into that account.

I have two users I can log onto (created when I first started the MVC5 project), but their information is found nowhere in the SQL Server Object Explorer. I have no idea what table or database my website is using when I publish, but it is not the localdb which is created with new MVC projects like I wish it was.

How do I fix this problem. I have no idea what to google.

TL;DR
I want to use my localdb when I publish my site to IIS when I click the 'Web Publish' button in Visual Studio 2015. Instead it's using an invisible database I cannot find.

Comment: Not really sure what you're talking about here, but localdb only exists within Visual Studio. There's no way at all to utilize it once your site is published and running outside Visual Studio.

Comment: @ChrisPratt so how do I grab those premade tables, and throw them onto one of my internal databases, and redirect the account stuff for that, without messing everything up?

Comment: Database migrations should be part of your deployment strategy. This post of mine may be helpful: http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/. As far as altering your connection strings goes, you'll want to use config transforms for that: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @ChrisPratt You are a beautiful person!! How you had this article ready to go is amazing! Thank you, this was exactly what I was looking for, I had had no idea how to word it. Could you put it in as answer, so I can mark this as solved? Thank you!